# Condensate drain does not drain properly

Tags: air-conditioning

My air handler is located in the garage and for some reason it will not drain properly until the fan shuts off.Unfortunately I cannot figure out how to add a photo but it has a vent pipe coming out of the air handler then a trap leading to outside

Comment: Try uploading the photo to [imgur](https://imgur.com) then posting a link here...

Comment: I found that a dirty filter caused a vacuum to build in air handler which pulled hard enough to hold water inside until the fan shut off.

Comment: I voted you up so you should have the rep needed to add add a picture now. However, my suspicions are that it's something similar to what Kris mentined.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the vent pipe is the same size as the drain line coming from the coil and is before the trap. Also the trap has to be of sufficient size and has a lot of fall, so any negative pressure remaining after the vent will not cause the drain to reverse and keep the water from draining from the rest of the piping going to the outside.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem.  The installer did not install a trap in the condensate line and also did not cap the cleanout.  Once I added one and capped off the cleanout, all has been draining correctly.

[Air handler condensation draining problem](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/48076/air-handler-condensation-draining-problem)

Comment: If this is the exact same problem the question should be flagged as a duplicate and closed.